# How to trigger Multibranch Pipeline build with github webhook

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

In freestyle job there is an option named "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" on stage Build Trigger.

screen capture here:

[image: screen capture here].

Together with webhook in gitlab config "http://myjenkins/gitlab/notify_commit" it works fine, meaning that the build will be triggered automatically when something is pushed to the repository. 
But why in Multibranch Pipeline there is only one option named "Periodically if not otherwise run"? Is there some plug-in not installed? How to trigger Multibranch Pipeline build with github webhook like freestyle job

Answer (score 21):

[This](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/) page described how to configure pipeline-as-code on multibranch workflow in jenkins.

This is the quote from the description inside:

> The Workflow Multibranch feature (provided by the workflow plugin) provides the following key abilities:
>
> - Automatic Workflow (job) creation in Jenkins per new branch in the
>   repo **(assuming webhooks are registered from GH to Jenkins)**.
> - Build specific to that child-branch and its unique scm change and build history.
> - Automatic job pruning/deletion for branches deleted from the repository, according to the settings.
> - Flexibility to individually configure branch properties, by overriding the parent properties, if required.

To configure the webhooks, refer to [this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-webhook-configuration) page.

To check if the events notify your jenkins you can use this feature below:
[image]

*PS: Watch the URL target that you configured, if you miss the "/" at the end of url it might not be able to reach the jenkins.*

I hope this helps!

Comment: Adding web hook doesnt helps when multi branch pipeline is configured to use GIT ( with credentials).

Comment: @TechFree So, is it not possible to trigger web-hook from Bitbucket Cloud to Jenkins if we have configured GIT as source provider? Is there any way to trigger webhook using GIT as provider instead of Bitbucket or Github?

Comment: The `Workflow Multibranch` plugin is archvied now