# Multi branch pipeline does not trigger when a change is pushed to a particular branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops, githooks

We have a GitHub repository which has 4 branches. A multibranch pipeline is setup for it in Jenkins.

Tried setting up webhook, but could not find an option to do so. It has option at branch level to setup a webhook.

Requirement is to setup a webhook at repository level, so that we do not have to set up webhook for every new branch added.

After setting up webhook at repository level, if a change is pushed to any of the branches under it, build should be triggered for that branch.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested the [GitHub-Webhook-Pipeline-Multibranch plugin](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003019232-GitHub-Webhook-Pipeline-Multibranch)? It seems to achieve your goal.

Also, there is another [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314483/how-to-trigger-multibranch-pipeline-build-with-github-webhook#44403235) with an answer that, while not accepted it has been up-voted by several people, and it might be of help in this case.