# Why 'add credentials' under 'add GitHub server' in Jenkins 'configure system' is not working?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline

I am following this post [How to trigger Multibranch Pipeline build with github webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314483/how-to-trigger-multibranch-pipeline-build-with-github-webhook) to setup an existing multibranch pipeline.

As a sub step to configure the webhook, I am redirected to this page https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-Integration-Webhooks?page=47.

Then I am stuck at its very first step:

[image]

There are no credentials to select from dropdown, and if I try 'Add', it will show Jenkins credential provide as usual.

[image]

But the problem is, after I type in my github username and password and click add, it will go back but nothing gets added!!

Why is this happening?

I have set up new Jenkins items before, and when I configure those pipeline items, I also need to provide credential for build source, i.e. github. It always works. Only this time problem is happening when I am doing 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Configure system'.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

Can't believe Jenkins has this many issue.

Here's where i found that solution: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/534

- Navigate to Jenkins > Credentials > System > Global Credentials
- Add Credential
- Select Secret Text from dropdown menu
- Add description (name of account, reason, etc.)
- In secret text box, deposit your Github Personal Access Token (GPAT)
- Save and navigate back to Jenkins > Global Configuration
- Find your Github Server Access section and select your credentials from it, then click Test Connection

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

- In `configuration/GitHub/Crentials` only can view `Secret text`
- In the job crenditials only can view `Username with password`, though username actually not useful at all

And in above two scenario you can use Github access token and no problem